# Running into issues when using BLOB with PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, lob

I have the following PLSQL code:

```
declare 
v_exec_obj_strng    varchar2(4000); 
p_map_name varchar2(40) := 'TEST'; 
p_key      number  := 4; 
p_checksum  varchar2(40) := '111111111111111'; 
p_value     blob := 11111111111111111111; 

begin 
v_exec_obj_strng := 'insert into my_table(name, key, chksum, value) values (''' || p_map_name || ''', ' || p_key || ', ''' || p_checksum || ''', ''' || p_value || ''')';
dbms_output.put_line(v_exec_obj_strng); 
end;
/
```

and I am getting this error: 
`PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed`

thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You can't just assign an integer value to a blob like that.

You can assign a RAW value to a BLOB using `TO_BLOB`:

```
p_value     blob := to_blob(UTL_RAW.CAST_FROM_NUMBER(11111111111111111111));
```

Or look at [the DBMS_LOB package](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS603) for more examples of how to assign values to BLOBs. Especially look at `CONVERTTOBLOB` and `LOADBLOBFROMFILE`.

Edit: to clarify, DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB only works for character data, and it's overly complicated. Please just give an example of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to use the `CONVERTTOBLOB` based on my code above?

Comment: Ehh... no, it's too messy. But I edited my example to show how to insert a number into a blob.